# Fabric Beta: new build alert

Tags: ios, google-fabric, crashlytics-beta

I've noticed that I get a "New Build Available" alert from Beta even if the new build has an older version string than the previous build. 
Example: the current release is 8.4.0. My CI build pushes a patch build of an older version such as 7.16.1 to Fabric. A user running 8.4.0 gets an alert that they can upgrade to 7.16.1

It seems like Beta is just sorting releases by deployment time. Is there a way to sort using semantic versioning?

Answer (score 5):

Paul from Fabric here. Currently, Beta only supports time-based versioning of deployments. It's good to know you'd love to see this added in though!